# SSIS Process Task failed to Create Zip File via PowerShell command - the zip folder appears and disapers

Tags: powershell, ssis

Please can anyone help me on this question:

SSIS Process Task failed to Create Zip File via PowerShell command - the zip folder appears and disappears immediately . The Progress says
[Execute Process Task] Progress: Operation Complete - 0 percent complete

```
"-windowstyle hidden -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -Command 
\"compress-archive -Force -path '"+ @[User::econ_cap_export_dir] 
+"\\CCC_Exp_*.txt' -destinationpath '"+@ 
[User::econ_cap_export_dir]+"\\CCC_Exp_"+ @[User::timestamp_str] +"_"+ (DT_WSTR, 3) @[User::delivery_nr] +".zip' -compressionlevel Optimal 

\""
```

Thank you !

Comment: Actually it also [Execute Process Task] Progress: Operation Complete - 100 percent complete

Comment: Why the zip file is created out of the folder even if I use directly PowerShell command?

Comment: Compress-Archive -Path ('D:\Apps\EconomicCapitalBridge\ExportsBackup\RDM' + "\" + "CCC_Exposure_*.txt") -DestinationPath ('D:\Apps\EconomicCapitalBridge\ExportsBackup\RDM' +  'CCC_Exposure_' + '1' + '.zip')

Comment: It should be creating inside 'D:\Apps\EconomicCapitalBridge\ExportsBackup\RDM' yet is creating on 'D:\Apps\EconomicCapitalBridge\ExportsBackup\'

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I am having an issue where a 1.3mb file appears to be causing the task to crash, yet compress-archive supports up to 2gb so I don't understand why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

In case you run in a problem like mine, try to kill processes . It solved to me.